# in a relativelayout how to position a textview in the middle of another textview above

Tags: android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to achieve the following output. I have 2 `TextView` centrally split and below they have each a substring centered respectively to their parent strings:

[image]

where suba and subb would be centered with their parent string.
In my XML I have hardcoded the value but I'd like to use a method which works whatever the screen size.

How could I do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/st_mid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/st_mid"
        android:text="This is text A"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textaa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/texta"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="suba"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/st_mid"
        android:text="This is text B"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textbb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textb"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="subb"
        android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, too early in the morning...

I found a solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/st_mid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/st_mid"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texta"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is text A"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textaa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/texta"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="suba"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/st_mid"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is text B"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textbb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textb"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="subb"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```